# Separar string do final para o começo com substr php

Tags: php

Olá, Eu me deparo com strings desse tipo:

> Emirates EK 262
>
> Air Canada AC 091
>
> Lan Airlines LA 761

Eu sei que do final para o início a quantidade não muda, ou seja, se eu quero pegar o nome primeiro nome, independente se ele é ou não um nome composto, eu começo contando da parte do final para frente, que não terei erros.

Eu preciso pegar o nome sem o prefiro de 2 digitos e o numero de 3 digitos.
ou seja, no meu substr, eu sei que a posição que eu começo é -7. Agora o problema é como que eu faço pra pegar o que está pra frente disso, do final para o início?

```
$mais_detalhes['operado_por'] = substr($trecho[4],-7,*O que coloco aqui?);
```

Comment: Qual deve ser a string de saida? talvez nem precise do `substr()`

Comment: Dê um exemplo do que você precisa. Antes e Depois. Lendo o que escreveu não consegui entender o que você quer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se entendi corretamente você quer "toda a *string* menos os 7 últimos caracteres".

De acordo com a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php):

> Se *length* [o terceiro parâmetro] for dado e for negativo, então esta quantidade de caracteres serão omitidos do final de string.

Dessa forma utilize:

```
substr("Lan Airlines LA 761", 0, -7);
```

Comment: kk, eu consegui resolver e foi dessa maneira mesmo, mas mesmo assim, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o `str_replace` após pegar pegar a string do final com o `substr`

```
trim(str_replace(substr($value, -7), '', $value))
```

**Resultados:**

> Emirates
>
> Air Canada
>
> Lan Airlines

*Obs: troque a variável `$value` pela sua variável da string*